# Belkin F5D8633-4 as wireless bridge / repeater

Tags: wireless-networking, router, bridge

I'm trying to improve WiFi coverage around my home by re-purposing an old Belkin router to use as a bridge. It's not practical to physically cable it up to the primary household router.

Searching online suggests that I should be able to select "Use as Access Point" in the set-up menu, but that option isn't available to me. I'm using (what appears to be) the latest firmware (v1.01.06)

For example the manual [here](http://cache-www.belkin.com/support/dl/p75555ea_f5d8633-4_man.pdf), whereas my router has "Wireless Protected Setup" in its place.

Is there a way around this, different firmware, or am I just out of luck with the version I have?

Answer (score 2):

This article below explains how to use your Router as an Access Point when the option does not exist.

https://www.belkin.com/us/support-article?articleNum=8067

Quote from article

> Step 1: Open a web browser to access the router's web-based setup
>   page.  For instructions on how to access the router's web-based setup
>   page using a Windows® computer, click here.  If you're using a Mac®
>   computer, click here.
>
> Step 2: Go to Wireless > Channel and SSID and configure your AP's
>   wireless network name (SSID).
>
> NOTE:  To configure your network's security, go to Wireless >
>   Security.  Ensure to always save settings before proceeding to the
>   next step.
>
> Step 3: Once the wireless settings have been configured, go to the
>   Wireless section, click Use as Access Point.

Comment: Thank you. Seems, This needs LAN connection between two routers. Any way to set this up with LAN connection? I got Tenda router and Belkin router being used as Repeater. Tenda doesnt have bridging option , so unable to add belkin wifi. Works ok when connected using wired lan.

Comment: Works ok when connected using wired lan   ....  That is is very standard way to look up two devices if bridging is not available.

Comment: Sorry for limited knowledge. Is there any way to make bridging available on old belkin f7d1301